# Is intmax_t the same as long long int?

Tags: c, posix

By POSIX, `intmax_t` designates a signed integer type capable of representing any value of any signed integer type.

Would it be correct that in C99/C11 that `intmax_t` is always the same size as `long long int`?

Comment: C99/C11 defined `intmax_t` _and_ `long long`.  Why would a language specification define 2 integer types that always do exactly the same thing? Of course they may be different.

Answer (score 15):

No. `intmax_t` can be an extended integer type larger than `long long`. I'm not aware of any systems that have it defined as such, but you should not assume in application code that they're the same. (Assuming they're the same in OS code may be acceptable if your OS always guarantees that, but it's still probably a bad idea.)

Comment: Agreed.  I see nothing in C11 that guarantees `long long int` to be the largest possible integer type.  There can be integer types larger than `long long int` and C11 requires that those be representable within `intmax_t`, however that would leave `intmax_t` larger than `long long int`.  @user19192, your assumption is *reasonable* so I'd just put these `sizeof` checks into a makefile or build process so for the *rare* platform that breaks your assumption, you'll know about it soon.

Comment: GNU C has the 128-bit integer type `__int128` as an extension. Is this an example of the integer types larger than `long long` that you're talking about? If it is, then it seems strange to that `long long` and `intmax_t` are 64-bits on my machine, while `__int128` is 128-bits.

Comment: Formally, `__int128` is not an extended integer type since `inttype_t` is required to be the largest signed integer type including extended integer types. It's just something you're supposed to pretend doesn't exist from the point of view of conforming programs. :-)

Comment: `inttype_t` should have been `intmax_t`. Sorry 4+ years is a little bit past SO's edit window..

Answer (score 8):

**[C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)**

*6.2.5 Types* tells us about "extended signed integer types":

> 4 There are five standard signed integer types, designated as signed char, short
>   int, int, long int, and long long int. (These and other types may be
>   designated in several additional ways, as described in 6.7.2.) There may also be
>   implementation-defined extended signed integer types
>   The standard and extended
>   signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types. 29)
>
> 29) Therefore, any statement in this Standard about signed integer types also applies to the extended
>   signed integer types.

*7.18.1.5 Greatest-width integer types* says that `intmax_t` is the largest possible "signed integer type", thus including extended ones:

> 1
>   The following type designates a signed integer type capable of representing any value of
>   any signed integer type:
>
> ```
> intmax_t
> ```

*6.4.4.1 Integer constants* then makes it pretty clear that the extended integer types might be larger than any of the standard ones:

> 6 If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an
>   extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value.